# How to undestand an unknown git repository

Tags: git

I would like to know the efficient way one person from my team could completely understand an unknown git repository from scratch (i.e. i don't provide them any detail) ?

Take the situation depicted herebelow

[image: Repo_structure]

How could a person from my team quickly and efficiently know the complete structure of the repository ?

How can he know that two branches exist ?

How can he know the reasons  of these two branches ? (assuming they will never be merged and will stay as is)

I am asking because it seems that to efficiently retrieve branches, one must first know that they exist. Or does cloning the entire repository and then do a git log is the right answer ?

Comment: Uh...run `git branch --list`?

Comment: Can you do that on a remote?

Comment: From the documentation: `Option -r causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option -a shows both local and remote branches.`. I suggest you all go through some Git tutorials, since these aren't even very advanced things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to clone the repository, then do `git branch --list` (or just `git branch`) on your local machine to list out the branches.

When you clone a repository in git, you always get the complete history, including all branches.

As for knowing the *reasons* for the branch, git doesn't manage that. It's up to your team to manage the reasons for creating a branch. For example, you might want to require that the initial commit always includes a reason, or a link to a ticket in a ticket tracking system, or a link to a story in a story tracking system.